# How do I export a vector-based HTML5 Canvas to a SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

Recently, I've found [Nova Skin](http://minecraft.novaskin.me/) and it's a browser-based Minecraft character renderer.
I would like to know how I can export the `#display` canvas element content to the scalable vector graphic format, rather than the portable network graphics format by default.

The  `#display` canvas uses vector graphics to render the shapes, but I haven't been able to find a way to export these shapes to a vector graphic.

Also, I've tried using [Canvas2SVG](http://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/) and couldn't figure out how to properly use it on the canvas element and export it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Canvas is a raster format and SVG is a vector format. All you can do is intercept the commands as Canvas2SVG does. I suggest you add your work so far to get Canvas2SVG to work so we can see what you're trying to do and whether it can be corrected.

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is that I don't know what to do with Canvas2SVG. It does something, I suppose. But, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: There are examples on the site, did you try running them? Your question is so vague at the moment it's impossible to answer.

Comment: By the time content is rendered onto #display, all the drawing commands  required to create that content are long gone. So you can't convert rendered canvas content into SVG. As @RobertLongson says, you must capture the drawing commands that Nova Skin uses to draw its content. Canvas2SVG converts those commands into SVG markups that can be embedded on a webpage or `drawImage`'ed back to the canvas. **But why are you trying to convert canvas to svg and back again?** Wouldn't it be easier to just export #display with `.toDataURL` and use the .png to drawImage on other canvases?

Comment: @markE I need to export the canvas to an SVG, png is not what I need.

Comment: Ok, then (as in my comment), examine Nova Skin's code and figure out how to capture the canvas drawing commands which you can then feed into Canvas2SVG.